# Loop through Scenario arguments capybara

Tags: arguments, capybara

I have the scenario below

When (/^ I select two files/) do |arg1,arg2|
end

I don't want to repeat code when I select seven files. Is there a way I can loop through arg1,arg2. The same code should work when I pass 5 / 7 arguments.

When (/^ I select files/) do |arg1,arg2, arg3,arg4|
Loop through args
do what ever you want....
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your regex should read,

```
When(/^I select "2" files$/) do |num|

    num.to_i
    <whatever else>
end
```

Or use a table and pass the name of the file to select

```
| test.text |
| apples.doc|
```

Ets

Answer (score 0):

Had you tried browswer.all('a').each ?

You can use xpath too broswer.xpath('//a'), or something like browser.xpath("//div[@id='divid'//a").